# How do I convert a Hawaiian guitar to Spanish Guitar?

Tags: guitar, lutherie

I have a 4 months old hawaiian guitar.  I do not like playing the Hawaiian guitar, and I want to change instruments. I have a standard bengali Hawaiian guitar with all its accessories and I want to play spanish acoustic guitar. How do I convert it into spanish guitar?

[image: 4 months old hawaiian guitar]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this is asking. Would you be willing to clarify?

Comment: I like the "Yemaha" brand name. Close, but no cigar ...  ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your guitar has ball end steel strings. By the look of the photo, all you need to do is buy a set of nylon strings and secure them to the wooden bridge using the traditional loop knot. The metal trapeze tailpiece can be removed. If this is difficult, just place a little bit of padding between it and the guitar top. Your photo doesn't show the headstock, but it's likely you have smaller diameter steel capstans on the tuning machines, rather than the larger diameter plastic ones fitted to classical/spanish guitars. They will work fine; just attach the strings to the capstans as normal. BTW, I love the cross culturality suggested by, 'standard bengali Hawaiian guitar'.